# prevent multiple form submission on keyup ajax post

Tags: ajax, post

I am currently working on a form for a retail outlet where in I need to submit form on enter keyup and redirect the form to the same page. On enter keyup the ajax post is being submitted to a php function and on successful data insert I am doing a page redirect. Which I am able to do currently, but in few instances the users are hitting the enter key multiple times (may be 3 to 4 times in a sec) because of which the for is being submitted multiple times. How do I prevent multiple submission. Have tried to generate a random number and pass as session token but, each submission is generating a new random number. 
Here is my code

```
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
        var postData = $("#invoiceForm").serialize();    
        $.ajax({
            url: "addsale()",
            type: "post",
            data: postData
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag variable to ignore the new request if not completed previous , it will work as a lock.

```
var isOnWay=false;
$(document).keyup(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
    var postData = $("#invoiceForm").serialize();    
    $.ajax({
        url: "addsale()",
        type: "post",
        before:function(){
               if(isOnWay)
                  return false; // ignore request
               isOnWay=true;// start a lock flag
                },
        complete:function(){
                 isOnWay=false; //free up
                },
        data: postData
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch the form onsubmit handler to prevent submission.
    Var isFormAlreadyPosted = false;
    $('form').submit(function(evt){

```
    If(isFormAlreadyPosted){
        evt.preventDefault()
    }
    isFormAlreadyPosted = true;
});
```